# How can I make ArrayPlot use one pixel per plot point?

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation

If I `ArrayPlot` an `{1200,1600}` matrix, the result is a plot with `ImageDimensions` of `{360,273}` pixels:

```
ArrayPlot[RandomReal[{0, 1}, {1200, 1600}]];
ImageDimensions[%]
```

> {360, 273}

I can't find an scaling option. How can I get a plot with a resolution of `{1200,1600}`?

Comment: `ImageDimensions` returns the number of displayed pixels not the number of blocks used by `ArrayPlot`

Comment: But I would like to get an image of the same dimensions as the original matrix. How can I get that?

Comment: This should work `ArrayPlot[RandomReal[1,{100,100}],PixelConstrained->True,ImageSize->{100,100}]`

Answer (score 5):

You're looking for `PixelConstrained -> 1`:

```
ArrayPlot[RandomReal[{0, 1}, {500, 500}],
 Frame -> False, PixelConstrained -> 1]
```

You should know that when it says it's pixel-constrained, it really means it. You can't resize the output pattern because it's being matched pixel-by-pixel to the physical pixels of your monitor. This may sound like a good thing but some patterns can appear too "harsh" because of this.

And remember that you always have the option of using `Image`:

```
Image[RandomReal[{0, 1}, {500, 500}]]
```